# Как передать переменную с формы в метод на другой странице

Tags: php, yii2, form

Я новичок, еле код понимаю. Разьясните пожалуйста, что я не так делаю и как надо.

Нужно в методе dataProviderAdmin получать $_POST или $_GET переменную из кастомной формы.
По ней отдельно находить все похожие ID пользователей из таблицы user.
Полученные ID подставлять в запрос $query.

Это форма во вьюшке

```
...
                <form method="get">
                <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail пользователя" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Искать">
                </form>
                <?= $f_email=$_GET['mail'];
                $inp = new pplInput();// здесь ругается "Undefined variable: inp"
                $inp->setInput($f_email);?> 

            <?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                ...
```

Стандартный контроллер с классом который я написал чтобы хранить и передавать данные формы

```
public function actionIndex()
{   
  $searchModel = new TicketHeadSearch();
  $dataProvider = (new TicketHead())->dataProviderAdmin();
    Url::remember();
        return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,  
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

class pplInput{               //класс чтоб передавать данные формы
    public $f_email;
    public function setInput($f_email){ 
        $this->f_email = $f_email;
    }
    public function getInput(){
        return $this->f_email;
    }
}
```

Модель

```
public function dataProviderAdmin()
{
                $inp->getInput();
                if (! empty($f_email))
                {
                    $query  = (new \yii\db\Query())
                    ->select('id')
                    ->from('user')
                    ->where(['like', 'email', $f_email])
                    ->all();
                } else 
                {
                    $query = TicketHead::find()->joinWith('user');
                }

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'updated_at' => SORT_DESC
            ]
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20
        ]
    ]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: <form action="../../../models/TicketHead.php" method="get">

Comment: Все не так делаешь. Рекомендую почитать документацию по фреймворку. Можно попробовать сгенерировать CRUD и посмотреть, как там реализовано получение и отрисовка данных.